# Unable to compile an F# type extension that's defined in a different module when compiling a C# client

Tags: f#

I'm unable to compile an F# type extension that's defined in a different module when compiling a C# client.

**Events.fs**

I have the following type:

```
type RegistrationSubmissionEvent =
    | RegistrationSucceeded of Profile
    | RegistrationFailed    of ValidatedForm
```

**EventExtraction.fs**

I implemented a type extension for the RegistrationSubmissionEvent in a separate module:

```
type RegistrationSubmissionEvent with
    member x.TryGetProfile() = 
           match x with
           | RegistrationSucceeded profile -> Some profile
           | _                             -> None
```

**C# Client:**

```
var viewmodel =  new ProfileEditorViewmodel(args.TryGetProfile().Value, SaveProfile());
```

**Issue:**

The issue is even when I import the EventExtraction module in my C# code, it still does not recognize TryGetProfile as a function of the type.

Note, this code works if I have the type extension in the same module as the discriminated union type.

Comment: In your C# code, did you also import the namespace in which the extension method is defined?

Comment: I did but it didn't make a difference. I can record a quick video to demo the issue if that would be helpful...

Comment: @FyodorSoikin - Actually, I imported the "module" and not the namespace. Perhaps I should define the type extension under a namespace and not a module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want your extension methods to be visible in C#, you should use the syntax for C#-style extension methods.

```
open System.Runtime.CompilerServices

[<Extension>]
type RegistrationSubmissionEventExtension () =
    [<Extension>]
    static member TryGetProfile (x : RegistrationSubmissionEvent) = 
         match x with
         | RegistrationSucceeded profile -> Some profile
         | _                             -> None
```

To explain why it works when you put the extension in the same module you should take a look at the difference between intrinsic and optional extensions on [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/type-extensions), but in short, if they're in the same module the extension methods will actually be added into the type itself (and consequently are available via reflection too).

Comment: I believe the F# type extension feature existed before extension methods were added to C#, which is why there are now two ways to do extension in F#.

Comment: Updated to: type RegistrationSubmissionEventExtension () =